Finding equilibrium solution from Fokker-Planck equation for planer Brownian rotator
In Andrew Zwanzig's Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics, the author has given the expression of the equilibrium density distribution function for a planer Brownian rotator.
Given the equations of motion (Langevin equations):
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \Omega
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I\frac{d\Omega}{dt} = -\zeta\Omega+\delta F(t)
\end{equation}
we can write the Fokker-Planck equation for the distribution function $f(\theta,\Omega)$ as (eq: 2.79) - 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -\Omega\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\zeta}{I}\frac{\partial}{\partial \Omega}(\Omega f)+\frac{\zeta k_B T}{I^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \Omega^2}f.
\end{equation}
After this the author has written down the expression of the equilibrium density distribution function $f_{eq}(\theta, \Omega)$ as (eq: 2.78) - $$f_{eq}(\theta, \Omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \frac{I}{2\pi k_B T} \right)^{1/2} \text{exp}\left(-\frac{I}{2k_BT}\Omega^2 \right).$$
My doubt is -
It is clear that Fokker-Planck equation contains $\theta$ as well as $\Omega$. And equilibrium solution means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$. So why there is no $\theta$-dependency in the $f_{eq}$ expression? What is the proper way to calculate it?
Another question -
Suppose we have the following Langevin equation- $$\gamma\dot{x}=v_0\text{cos}\phi+\xi(t)$$ along with $$\frac{d\phi}{dt}= \omega+\xi_{\phi}.$$
Theoretically, can we calculate $\langle x(t)\rangle$ (noise-average) by solving the corresponding Fokker-Planck equation? If yes, is 'equilibrium' requirement is fundamental?

You can check that $f_{eq}$ is a stationary solution. It is merely uniform in $\theta$. This is expected from rotational invariance:
$$
\theta\to\theta+\phi\quad \Omega\to\Omega
$$
In fact, the first $\frac1{2\pi}$ factor is a normalisation for this extra angular degree of freedom.
Careful, a stationary state is when $\partial_tf = 0$. Equilibrium is more restrictive and requires the vanishing of the probability current. Actually, in this case it is not rigorously equilibrium as there is still a current in the $\theta$ direction. However, there no current in the $\Omega$ direction. In fact, by setting the latter to zero:
$$
j_\Omega := \frac\zeta I\Omega f+\frac{\zeta k_BT}{I^2}\partial_\Omega f = 0
$$
you recover the announced Boltzmann distribution when solving for $f$. This remaining current is characteristic of Hamiltonian systems.
For your second problem, since you are only interested in averages, there is no need to solve the Fokker-Planck equation. Just solve for the mean. From your notation, I gather that $\omega$ is constant, in which case, $\phi$ follows a biased random walk. You can compute $\langle \cos\phi\rangle$ by noticing that $\phi$ is Gaussian and computing instead the characteristic function:
$$
\langle e^{i\phi}\rangle = e^{i\langle\phi\rangle-\Delta\phi^2/2}
$$
by performing the usual Gaussian integral with the translation change of variable. In your case, $\langle\phi\rangle = \omega t$ and $\Delta\phi^2 = D_\phi t$ with $D_\phi$ the angular diffusion constant given by the strength of $\xi_\phi$. There is no need for Ito's lemma.

How do we have the last expression, can you please give some hint? Do we need some "Ito's lemma" to get the orientational time correlation function?
